# Search for a file in a Far Manager panel like FreeCommander Quick Search

Tags: file-search, far-manager

How do I make search for file in Far Manager that is in the current directory of the selected panel? In FreeCommander, this can be done just by typing file's name.

Answer (score 13):

You can do this by holding down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and typing the file name.

Comment: Please review [How To Answer](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-answer) to avoid having your answer flagged for low quality in future.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Midnight Commander?

Comment: @RandallStevens: Yes, by pressing Alt-S (ESC-S).

Answer (score 2):

There is also [QSearchSwitch](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/QSearchSwitch) plugin. It was just a funny exercise for me, but may be interesting for someone. The idea is to invert the meaning of <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. When you type letters in Far command line - QSearch appears. If you want to type in Far CommandLine - press Alt+«letter». After first symbol (when CommandLine is not empty) you may release Alt.

**Installation**

- Unpack to %FARHOME%\Plugins\QSearchSwitch folder
- Restart Far Manager
- Current version of plugin requires Far 3.x 2798 or lower